# jquery: return html from div and not children

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

If I click on `#parent` I want to return the text inside it and **not** return the text inside nested
 layers (`#child-parent`, `#child`)

```
<div id='parent'>
   this text is for parent

   <div id='child-parent'> 
     this text if for child-parent  

       <div id='child'>
        and this text is for child.   
       </div>   

   </div>

</div>
```

this:
`$('#parent').html() = "this text is for parent"`

and not this:
`$('#parent').html() = "this text is for parent this text is for child-parent and this text is for child"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab it like this:

```
$('#parent').clone().children().remove().end().html()
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NDuWy/), you may want a [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) call on there though, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NDuWy/1/).

Another alternative is to loop though the text nodes, like this:

```
$('#parent').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).text()
```

[You can test that here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NDuWy/2/) or [the trimmed version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NDuWy/3/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've discovered existence of three new jquery methods :)

Answer (score 4):

If the structure always looks like this, you can call:

```
var mytext = $('#parent').contents().first().text();
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/